# Cellfun is reordering my matrix when I try to clear the NaN's from it

Tags: matlab, nan

I am having some trouble with Matlab right now.  I am currently trying to remove all the NaN's from a large Cell Array I have 3806 x 122.  I have been looking at solutions from similar problems, and I came up with.

```
data(cellfun(@(x) any(isnan(x(:))), data)) = [];
```

My matrix is kind of weird because it looks like this

```
(ex).
1    2    3    4    5    5    NaN
6    5    2    5    6    7    NaN
2    3    4    5    6    7    NaN
NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

My problem is when I apply the line of code above to my array I get an output of this with no NaNs.

```
1    2    3    4    5    5    6    5    2    5    6    7    2    3    4    5    6    7    etc...
```

I don't understand why it does this.  I also have to be careful with deleting the columns because each column has a corresponding title, and I don't want to mix them up.  It would be helpful if I could somehow index which columns and rows have the NaNs, so I could delete the corresponding the titles with them.

In the end, I want to put the titles and data into a dataset structure that looks like this.

```
(ex).
'title1'   'title2'   'title3'   'title4'   'title5'   'title6'
1          2          3          4          5          5
6          5          2          5          6          7
2          3          4          5          6          7
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Jonathan

Comment: Will the `NaN`'s always be in the last row and last column, or are they spread around? Are there rows/columns with both numbers and `Nan`'s (except for the last rows/cols)?

Comment: Robert, The vast majority of NaN's are in the bottom and side of the array like it is shown above, but there are some columns of NaN's dispersed throughout the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each cell only contains one element, you can use `cellfun(@isnan, data)`
instead of `cellfun(@(x) any(isnan(x(:))), data)`

If you are certain that there are always rows or columns full of NaN then you can use the first row and column of the logical index for indexing

```
I = ~cellfun(@isnan, data);
data = data(I(:,1), I(1,:));
```

and you can use `I(1,:)` to index the titles as well.
A more efficient way would be

```
Irow = ~cellfun(@isnan, data(:,1));
Icol = ~cellfun(@isnan, data(1,:));
data = data(Irow, Icol);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  This was just the thing I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are better ways than this, but here's what I came up with.  In my example, I'm replacing non-empty entries with empty entries, but you should be able to tweak for your case.

```
d = cell(10,4);
d{1} = 5;
d{4} = 10;
d
ix = cellfun(@(x) numel(x)>0,d);
d(ix) = cell(1,numel(sum(ix(:))));
d
```